# What is difference between Target Name and Output File in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I see both of these in the Property Pages. MS help is no help, as it discusses command line options. It does say "/out:filename" overrides the default output filename, but what is the default file name?

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Comment: Assuming this is about C++ (it is not very obvious), this wonky duplication came about in VS2010.  Back when they switched from the legacy VCBuild engine to MSBuild.  "Output File" needed to be retained to stay compatible with legacy projects.  But "Target Name" is what you should edit, you'll get a warning if they don't agree.  It defaults to the project name.

Answer (score 0):

Target name is the "base" name for the output, and it is by default set to the project name `$(ProjectName)`. The output file name is the the full path to the output file.

For example, if I have a static library project, **foo**, The target name would be **foo**, but the output file name can be **Release\foo.lib** in the "Release" build and **Debug\foo.lib** in the "Debug" build.

You can inspect it all in your project if open the property (open it a a combo box) and then click "Edit..." it will show both the variable name and the value.